# Android Google Map V2 Direction

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get the driving direction between the two positions -

**LatLng(15.244,45.85555) and
LatLng(78.459,97.4666).**

The code which i have tried -

```
 Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().
    add(new LatLng(15.244,45.85555),
    new LatLng(78.459,97.4666))
    .width(5).color(Color.RED));
```

But this draws a straight line between the two points .

Is there any other method/way to get the driving directions between these two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this way:

Create `GMapV2Direction`  class

```
public class GMapV2Direction {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";
public final static String MODE_BICYCLING = "bicycling";

ArrayList<String> str=new ArrayList<String>();


public GMapV2Direction() { }

public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&"+"mode="+mode;


    System.out.print(url);

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}
```

}

Defined this in your `Activity` like

```
    public final String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final String MODE_WALKING = "walking";
public final String MODE_BICYCLING = "bicycling";
```

Now, implement `AsyncTask` like this:

```
  class AsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    String mode_in = "";
    int duration ;
    String distance;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main2.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... aurl) {

        try {
            try {

                mode_in = aurl[0];

                Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition,aurl[0]);

                duration = md.getDurationValue(doc);
                distance = md.getDistanceText(doc);
                String start_address = md.getStartAddress(doc);
                String copy_right = md.getCopyRights(doc);


                    System.out.print(duration + distance + start_address
                            + copy_right);

                    directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);

                    rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(2);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        if (directionPoint.size() > 0) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                    rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                }

                if (rbDriving.isChecked()) {
                    mode = MODE_DRIVING;
                    rectLine.color(Color.RED);
                } else if (rbBiCycling.isChecked()) {
                    mode = MODE_BICYCLING;
                    rectLine.color(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (rbWalking.isChecked()) {
                    mode = MODE_WALKING;
                    rectLine.color(Color.BLUE);
                }

                tv_distance_time.setText("Duration: "+duration
                        +" ,Distance: "+distance);

                mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getParent());
            builder.setTitle("No route found");
            builder.setMessage("No route found");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            builder.create().show();
        }

    }
}
```

Called `AsyncTask` like

```
new AsyncTask1().execute(mode);
```

Hope this is works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the directions API.

Example:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=50.1,19.6&destination=52.666,20.0&sensor=false

You need to do background processing, parsing and displaying Polyline with a bunch of points.

[Documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Comment: thank you for replay but i have one question and my question is that can i draw a path between any two points??? is that possible in Google maps V2 API??